# LinerLayout не могу нормально добавить картинку

Tags: android-layout, android-linearlayout

Когда я добавляю картинку (+ текста) картинка растягивается на весь экран (по ширине)
`images.setImageResource(icon]`
Пробовал использовать setMaxWidth и setMaxHeight - результата нет

маленькие картинки раpтягивает. дело не в них

Верстка:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imageView" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
```

Код:

```
ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); 
image.setMaxHeight(150); 
image.setMaxWidth(150);
```

Comment: Покажите верстку, пожалуйста. Иначе это гадание на кофейной гуще получается

Comment: как это сделать ? xD

Comment: <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

Comment: ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        image.setMaxHeight(150);
        image.setMaxWidth(150);

Comment: У Вас параметры высоты и ширины стоят `wrap_content`, что по смыслу означает "займи столько места, сколько посчитаешь нужным". Выставьте жестко заданные размеры (можно, например, в процентах). Если не хотите, чтобы картинка при этом обрезалась, то в верстке поставьте `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: Внес информацию из Ваших комментариев в вопрос (кнопка править внизу вопроса)